# problem trying to read a csv file but the extension does not appear

Tags: python, pandas, csv

Well, I'm trying to open a CSV file from the Spotify Database, to work with its Sequential Skip Predictions dataset. But he has some problem with his columns and rows that I can't figure out how to fix. The most I could do was open the table ignoring some problems but it still gets very buggy.

The link is this:

[Link for Spotify Sequential Skip Prediction Challange](https://www.aicrowd.com/challenges/spotify-sequential-skip-prediction-challenge/dataset_files)

The file I'm trying to access is this:

Training_Set_And_Track_Features_Mini (17.2 MB)

I used this code here, which is what I managed to do to open it:

```
import pandas as pd

# path csv
path_file = '/content/drive/MyDrive/TESTE TCC/training mini/16772e7f-7871-4d42-a44f-5f399f40fd94_training_set_track_features_mini'

# Open CSV
data = pd.read_csv(file_path, encoding='latin1', error_bad_lines=False)

# display the data
data
```

but even so, it's still very buggy, and the columns are all weird

Comment: That link requires registration and logging in, so it's kind of hard to help here.

Answer (score 2):

This is a [tar.gz archive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gzip#Derivatives_and_other_uses), which you need to extract before using:

For this, run this shell command:

```
tar -xzf 16772e7f-7871-4d42-a44f-5f399f40fd94_training_set_track_features_mini.tar.tar
```

This will create a `data` folder that contains the CSV files.

Then, from your python script/notebook:

```
df_features = pd.read_csv('data/track_features/tf_mini.csv')

df_train = pd.read_csv('data/training_set/log_mini.csv')
```